# global variable not recognizing user inputed numbers

Tags: java, variables, input, scope

```
import java.util.Scanner;




public class Blackjack {

    class Commands {
        static final String yes = "yes";
        static final String no = "no";
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        //Opponent player2 = new Opponent();
        double AiCard1 = 0;
        double AiCard2 = 0;
        double AiCard3 = 0;
        double AiTotalcard3 = AiCard1 + AiCard2 + AiCard3;
        double card1 = 0;
        double card2 = 0;
        double card3 = 0;
        double card4 = 0;
        double total2 = card1 + card2 + card3 + card4;
        double total = card1 + card2 + card3;



        System.out.println("Hello and Welcome to my custom version of blackjack!");
        System.out.println("You will start off with $300");
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Do you want to read the rules before playing?");
        System.out.print("Press 1 if yes, press 2 for no");


            int choice = input.nextInt();
            switch (choice) {
            case 1: 
                System.out.println("You have 4 cards to get as close to 21 as possible.  Whoever is closest to 21 wins");
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }




        int balance = 300;

        System.out.println("Your bank balance is $" + balance);
        //user places a bet
        System.out.println("Place a bet");

        int bet = input.nextInt();
        System.out.println("You placed a bet of " + bet);

        //this is the AI 
        AiCard1 = Math.random() * 12 + 1;
        AiCard1 = Math.round(AiCard1);
        AiCard2 = Math.random() + 12 + 1;
        AiCard2 = Math.round(AiCard2);
        double AiTotal2cards = AiCard1 + AiCard2;
        if(AiTotal2cards < 15) {
            AiCard3 = Math.random() * 12 + 1;
            AiCard3 = Math.round(AiCard3);
            AiTotalcard3 = AiCard1 + AiCard2 + AiCard3;
        }



        card1 = Math.random() * 12 + 1;
        card1 = Math.round(card1);
        System.out.println("Your first card was a " + card1);
        System.out.println();

        card2 = Math.random() * 10 + 1;
        card2 = Math.round(card2);

        System.out.println("Your second card was a " + card2);
        System.out.println();

        System.out.println("Your cards add up to " + (card1 + card2));
        System.out.println("Do you want to add another card?");
        String answer = input.next();
        here:
        if(answer.equals(Commands.yes)) {

            card3 = Math.random() * 12 + 1;
            card3 = Math.round(card3);
            System.out.println("Your third card was a " + card3);
            System.out.println("Your cards add up to " + (card1 + card2 + card3));
            total = card1 + card2 + card3;

            if(total > 21) {
                System.out.println("You lose");
                break here;
            }
            System.out.println("Do you want to add another card?");


            String answer1 = input.next();
            if(answer1.equals(Commands.no)){
                break here;
            }
            if(answer1.equals(Commands.yes)) {

                card4 = Math.random() * 12 + 1;
                card4 = Math.round(card4);
                System.out.println("Your fourth card was a " + card4);
                System.out.println("Your cards add up to " + (card1 + card2 + card3 + card4));
                total2 = card1 + card2 + card3 + card4;

                if(total2 > 21) {
                    System.out.println("You lose");
                    break here;
                }
                break here;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Your total cards were " + total2);
        System.out.println("AI total cards were " + AiTotalcard3);
        input.close();

    }
}
```

When you run the program I was hoping that the variables at the top would have new numbers saved into them when the user went through the program.  Is there a better way to do this because the console output is always 0 for the total.

Comment: Can you explain what exactly doesn't work as expected? Like: `this statement prints X, but it should print Y`

Comment: `here:` ... you might want to avoid using labels in your Java code.

Comment: Hello and Welcome to my custom version of blackjack!
You will start off with $300

Do you want to read the rules before playing?
Press 1 if yes, press 2 for no2
Your bank balance is $300
Place a bet
50
You placed a bet of 50
Your first card was a 8.0

Your second card was a 7.0

Your cards add up to 15.0
Do you want to add another card?
yes
Your third card was a 2.0
Your cards add up to 17.0
Do you want to add another card?
no
Your total cards were 0.0
AI total cards were 0.0

Comment: So when the program runs it will give you a random number 1 - 12 and at the end it should count all the numbers you got and the person closest to 21 wins.  problem is that it is saying the total is 0 @JasonC

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First lets look at `AiTotalcard3`:

It shouldn't always output 0 for that, more precisely it will output 0 in the case where `AiCard1 + AiCard2 >= 15`, which probably happens a lot.

It makes sense if you trace through your actual code. The first thing that happens is those initializers:

```
double AiCard1 = 0;
double AiCard2 = 0;
double AiCard3 = 0;
double AiTotalcard3 = AiCard1 + AiCard2 + AiCard3;
```

So `AiTotalcard3` is initially set to 0. It will remain 0 until you change it, which happens here:

```
AiCard1 = Math.random() * 12 + 1;
AiCard1 = Math.round(AiCard1);
AiCard2 = Math.random() + 12 + 1;
AiCard2 = Math.round(AiCard2);
double AiTotal2cards = AiCard1 + AiCard2;
if(AiTotal2cards < 15) {
    AiCard3 = Math.random() * 12 + 1;
    AiCard3 = Math.round(AiCard3);
    AiTotalcard3 = AiCard1 + AiCard2 + AiCard3;
}
```

But that only happens if the first two cards add up to less than 15. After that you never touch `AiTotalcard3` again.

Your logic can be *greatly* simplified all around, and also it makes a lot more sense to use `int` instead of `double` for the cards, but ignoring all that and sticking to your current style, you could fix this by making sure *all* paths set `AiTotalcard3`, for example (again not the cleanest logic but just sticking to your pattern):

```
if(AiTotal2cards < 15) {
    AiCard3 = Math.random() * 12 + 1;
    AiCard3 = Math.round(AiCard3);
    AiTotalcard3 = AiCard1 + AiCard2 + AiCard3;
} else {
    AiTotalcard3 = AiCard1 + AiCard2; // be sure to always set it
}
```

Now, with all that in mind, you have a similar problem with `total2`: *Not all of your execution paths set the value of `total2`.* It works if you make it up to the 4th card but prior to that you never change it from its initial value of 0. So you're just going to have to go through this with a fine-toothed comb.

One of your fundamental issues is for some reason you're using different variables all over the place for the first 2 cards vs. all the cards. If you just used a single `aiTotal` and `total` to accumulate the card totals as you go, you'd avoid most of these issues.

Comment: That worked for the AiTotalcard but I am still having trouble with total showing up with a number that is not 0.  Also I have been self teaching myself java so thats why things are over complicated probably.

Comment: @TylerBull Right, but you need to apply the same technique that I used to fix the AI total to fix your total. Look through your code. Trace through it carefully. Find paths that lead to `total` not being set, and fix it. This has nothing to do with learning Java itself, it's more a general logical thinking and deductive reasoning task.

Comment: @TylerBull as an aside note, take a look at [Java Naming Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html) where variable names should be lowerCaseFirst, class names UpperCaseFirst, constants ALL_UPPER_CASE, etc

Answer (score 2):

I think your main issue is confusing `total` and `total2`. You seem to use both interchangeable in multiple places.

At first, if the user does not pick a third card, `total2` will always equal 0 because if the `if(answer.equals(Commands.yes)) {` is never entered, `total2` is never set past the original initialization of 0.

If the user picks a third card but not a fourth, you update the value of `total` correctly but not `total2`.

If the user picks a fourth card, then it should work correctly.

Besides the main fixes, here are some tips that you should keep in mind when writing your game:

1. You mention that the global variables are not recognized, but none of your variables are actually global. You should read up on what exactly that means.
2. I would suggest using ints or a custom datatype to store card values, as you would never need the decimal places a double provides.
3. Use loops in your structure to save a lot of code. It will make it cleaner and easier to understand.
4. Print what the AI is doing. There's no point to having an AI if you can't see its moves.

Anyway, good luck with your game! Programming can be intimidating at first but this is a great start.

Comment: Thanks, I know using Int's would be better but for times sake I kept everything as a double.  I will eventually convert them.